# Word PDF Export is missing text

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, export, print-to-pdf

Started with a complex document with many elements in Word 2013 ver 15.0.5049.1000 on Windows 10, which exported to PDF OK.

- Switched PDF/A on, and exported with ***File | Export | Create PDF | Options | Advanced | ISO 19005-1 compliant (PDF/A)*** ; but the export was missing the text.
- Switched PDF/A off, and exported with *'Bitmap text when fonts may not be embedded'* on (prior setting for this docx); the export is still missing text.
- Close Word, shutdown PC, reboot, reopen the docx and export to PDF; still missing text (which is Arial, BTW).

However, I can use ***File | Save As | PDF*** and get all contents that way.
How may I fix this docx so it can be exported once again to PDF within Word using its Export function, so I don't have to get my team to change their standardized macros?

Comment: Instead of using the export function, are you able to create a PDF of the document using the Save As function of Word?

Comment: What's your Word 2013 version number? I am using version 15.0.4569.1504 and no issue when clicking File | Export | Create PDF | Options | Advanced | ISO 19005-1 compliant (PDF/A) in Word. Try to update Office and create a new document for exporting.

Comment: Try in Control Panel > Programs and Features, to right-click Microsoft Office and choose Change. In the following repair dialog, choose Quick Repair, and if that doesn't help then repeat with Online Repair.

Comment: Better while export select,, **Optimize for Standard Publishing and from Options click BitmapText.**

Comment: Using Bitmap Text means the text cannot be viewed larger than the Word doc.

Comment: What text is missing? Can you narrow the problem down to a specific case?

Answer (score 1):

If a feature of Word has disappeared, Office might need to be repaired.

This is done in :

- Run Control Panel > Programs and Features
- Right-click "Microsoft Office ..." and choose *Change*.
- In the following repair dialog, choose *Quick Repair*
- If that doesn't help, repeat with *Online Repair*.

In extreme cases, the uninstall and re-install of Office may be required.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The question is about missing text, not missing Office features...

Comment: @oberlies: This post is from 2018, so you have arrived too late. In any case, when Office goes bad, repair is faster than reinstallation and might even help.

Comment: This site is not just about helping the OP, but also others with the same problem. For them, it is important to know, that this answer is not specifically addressing the question, but is just describing something one can also try...